# How to reach UIPopoverController from its content view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with iOS `UIPopoverController`. I have a `UIPopoverController` cleated like this:

```
- (UIPopoverController *)popover
{
    if (!_popover)
    {
        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.viewController];
    }

    return _popover;
}
```

Is it possible somehow to reach `UIPopoverController` class object `self.popover` inside of `ViewController` class?

Comment: why do you need popover in contentview ???

Comment: Inside of content view controller I want to dismiss popover controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good Option** : Use `delegate` to dissmiss popover from contentView.

**Another option** : In `iOS 8`, you can dismiss the popover by using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` from within the popover. **Note** it doesn't work in `iOS 7`.